# What is the intuition behind this acceleration formula?

Tags: acceleration, continuum-mechanics

What is the intuition behind this acceleration formula?

In another word, how to demonstrate this by using common sense without using chain rule?

[image]

Comment: Newton's laws aren't "common sense". There are no mechanical systems (with exception of planetary movement)  that Newton could have seen that actually obey Newton's laws. If you want to see mechanics according to Newton, you have to watch ISS videos. That's what Newtonian mechanics actually looks like.

Comment: @CuriousOne By the way what is ISS videos?

Comment: International Space Station. "Common sense" in Newtonian mechanics is people floating freely in space and throwing a ball will propel you backwards... objects in motion stay in motion... that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's imagine you walking down a tall mountain when the sun is setting. Let's say it is cold at the top of the mountain, so walking down the mountain tends to make you warmer. But also the sun is setting so you might get colder. How do you take both effects into account?

Well the change in temperature you feel (LHS) is the change in temperature at the position you are right now (RHS, first term) plus your velocity times the temperature gradient(RHS, second term). So the faster the sun goes down, the faster the temperature you experience changes. Also, the faster you move down the mountain the faster the temperature changes. And finally the steeper the temperature gradient, the faster the temperature changes.

But it is important to remember that the two terms on the right hand side are independent, and they can go in the same direction in opposite directions. For example, if you walk down the mountain the morning, then both terms will tend to make you warm up faster.